# SUM over separate WHERE clauses in GROUP BY with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inner-join

I have two mysql tables, one contains a list of hospitals and the other contains a list of metrics. I'm trying to compute state-wide summary statistics by performing a GROUP BY on the hospital table and an INNER JOIN with the metric table. I'm looking for multiple conditions in the summary table to sum across. This is what my database and query look like now ...

```
# create the hospital table and add 4 hospitals from 2 states
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hospital (
    hospital_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    state VARCHAR(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (hospital_id)
);
INSERT INTO hospital (name, state)
VALUES ('A', 'AL'), ('B', 'AL'), ('C', 'AK'), ('D', 'AK');


# create metrics table and add 2 metrics per hospital
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metric (
    metric_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    hospital VARCHAR(255),
    name VARCHAR(255),
    value INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (metric_id)
);
INSERT INTO metric (hospital, name, value)
VALUES ('A', 'total male patients', 100),
       ('A', 'total female patients', 110),
       ('B', 'total male patients', 55),
       ('B', 'total female patients', 50),
       ('C', 'total male patients', 10),
       ('C', 'total female patients', 7), 
       ('D', 'total male patients', 200),
       ('D', 'total female patients', 170);

# compute statewide metrics
SELECT
    hospital.state,
    metric.name,
    SUM(metric.value) as total
FROM
    hospital
INNER JOIN
    metric
ON
    hospital.name = metric.hospital
WHERE
    (metric.name = 'total male patients' OR metric.name = 'total female patients')
GROUP BY
    hospital.state,
    metric.name;
```

and this is the output ...

```
+-------+-----------------------+-------+
| state | name                  | total |
+-------+-----------------------+-------+
| AK    | total female patients |   177 |
| AK    | total male patients   |   210 |
| AL    | total female patients |   160 |
| AL    | total male patients   |   155 |
+-------+-----------------------+-------+
```

Is there a way to refactor my query so that I only get one row per state and one column per condition. For example ...

```
+-------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| state | total male patients | total female patients |
+-------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| AK    | 210                 |       177             |
| AL    | 155                 |       160             |
+-------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I refactored with a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT h.state,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.name = 'total male patients'
                THEN m.value ELSE 0
           END) AS total_male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.name = 'total female patients'
                THEN m.value ELSE 0
           END) AS total_female
FROM hospital h INNER JOIN
     metric m
     ON h.name = m.hospital
GROUP BY h.state
```

Note that I added table aliases.  I qualified the column names that make sense.  When you have more than one table in query, you should qualify all column names.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a case when for select the values in  2 columns

```
  SELECT
      state,
      Item,
      SUM(case when item = 'Total Veterans served' then Value else 0 end ) as total_Veterans_served, 
      SUM(case when item = 'N with PTSD'  then Value else 0 end ) as total_N_with_PTSD, 
  FROM va_location
  INNER JOIN patient_2015 ON va_location.facility_id = patient_2015.Location
  WHERE Category = 'Station-Level Stats'
  AND ValueType = 'Number'
  AND   (Item = 'Total Veterans served' OR Item = 'N with PTSD')
  GROUP BY
      state,
      Item
```